# Inheriting constructors in C++20 (Visual Studio 2019)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, c++20

I am using Visual Studio 2019 (v16.10.3) with /std:c++latest and this compiles:

```
class Base
{
public:
   Base(int x) {}
};

class Derived : public Base
{
// no constructors declared in Derived
};

int main() {
   Derived d(5);
}
```

For the previous versions of the standard I have to declare inherited constructors with the using directive:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
   using Base::Base;
};
```

Is this something new that was put in C++20 or is it some Microsoft specific thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this something new that was put in C++20 or is it some Microsoft specific thing?

Not with relation to inherited constructors. What changed is that aggregate initialization may use parenthesis under certain conditions. `Derived` is considered an aggregate on account of having no private parts, so we initialize its bases and members directly.

It even works when we add a public member:

```
class Base
{
public:
   Base(int ) {}
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
// no constructors declared in Derived
    int y;
};

int main() {
   Derived d(5, 4);
}
```

[Live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sYn2on7GSTjJKFta)

Answer (score 3):

This is the result of C++17 allowing classes with base classes to still be considered aggregates combined with C++20 rules allowing aggregate initialization to work with `()` constructor syntax if the values in the parentheses would work (and wouldn't call a constructor). So while it looks like a constructor call, it's actually aggregate initialization.

`Derived` doesn't have a constructor matching `Base`'s constructor; you're merely initializing the aggregate `Derived` by providing a valid initializer for its subobject `Base`.